# Symfony 3.3: FileNotFoundException after moving/renaming uploaded file

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3, symfony3.x

I have a form with a file upload field (limited to PDF format only). After the form has been submitted and a valid uploaded file is present, I rename and move the file. Then I try to display the page with the form again - at which point the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File` class constructor throws a `FileNotFoundException` because, for some reason, it's been handed the path to the no-longer-existing temp file.

Relevant facts:

- The form fields (including the file upload field) are not mapped to an entity because I'm using a Wordpress-style "meta" table for the additional data associated with the entity; the controller handles creating any new objects to be persisted.
- The new filename is successfully saved to the database; I've further verified that the error occurs with the $form->createView() call.
- Before anyone suggests that this was due to my PHP settings, note that I purposefully tried uploading a PDF file with a size below the limit.
- My temporary solution is to redirect to another page (there is no error when I do this), but longterm it's much more ideal to still show the form page after submitting the form.
- I tried overwriting the `UploadedFile` object I got from the form with the `File` object returned by the `->move()` method, but this didn't help.
- I also tried creating a child class of the built-in `FileType` class and changing the `data_class` to be `SplFileInfo` (the parent class of Symfony's `File` class) b/c `SplFileInfo` doesn't throw an exception over an invalid path, but this had no effect either.

My interpretetation of what's happening is that, for some reason, when you create a form view Symfony instantiates a new `File` object for the file upload field using the old, temporary file path - thus resulting in a fatal error that absolutely shouldn't be happening (because when would you ever not be moving the uploaded file?).

Any suggestions for things to try that I haven't thought of yet would be much appreciated!

---

#### Solved

I figured out the problem by looking at the stack trace - I have a Twig extension that was calling `Request::createFromGlobals()`, and THAT resulted in trying to create a new UploadedFile object with the no-longer-existing temp file path. Having the extension get the already-existing `Request` object in its constructor should prevent this.

Comment: Can you post (some of) your controller code? I suspect you're keeping the form throughout the process? Note the info [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html) just above the "Creating an Uploader Service" paragraph as that seems relevant.

Comment: @ccKep That's not the issue - this is happening when first uploading a file (as well as after a filename has been persisted, in which case I do create a new File object - not that it seems to do anything).

Comment: Posting the controller would still help I think.

Comment: I did; I just responded to you first.

Comment: Well, as far as I see you **are** using the un-altered form object? What does `$form->get($settingFile)->getData();` dump after `$em->flush();` ?

Comment: The same UploadedFile object from before the file renaming/moving/persistence stuff.